# Selenium webdriver disabled on browser start?

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using the Selenium Firefox web driver and attempting to start an existing profile which I have created  specifically for Selenium.

Firefox starts up with the correct profile, but the web driver shows as disabled in the extensions and therefore Selenium fails to connect to the web driver. How can I make sure that it starts with the extension enabled?

I would post code, but the code is working properly and the correct profile is used. This is a Firefox configuration issue I believe. If I let Selenium create a temp profile it works fine, but I need access to one of the extensions that I have setup as well as the configuration for that extension. I saw that it is possible to load extensions through code but I don't know how I could load an identical configuration.

Comment: Is there any webdriver addon in the profile yoou had created ?

Comment: The webdriver addon is only present when the profile is started via code. This is normal behavior. The problem is that rather than starting enabled as it normally does, the addon is starting disabled.

Comment: I have created a work-around by manually adding the add-on that I need to a new profile and then hard coding the preferences from the add-on for the temp profile. This works, however it is not the solution I was looking for.